# Как передать значения с одного декоратора функции в другой, возможно ли это?

Tags: python

есть декоратор, в нем функция , частью этой функции, есть специальной генератор значений, который записывает их в массив и этой массив нужно передать в другой декоратор для получения с него значений ..

```
    ...

# при старте бота, запускается каманда 'start'

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def handle_text(message):
    markup = telebot.types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(True)
    markup.row('I AM RANDOM')
    # Подключаемся к БД
    db_worker = SQLighter(config.database_name)
    # Получаем количество строк, формируем массив и перемешиваем его
    l = list(range(1, db_worker.count_rows() + 1))  # <<<<<<<
    random.shuffle(l)
    bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Welcome', reply_markup=markup)

# Отлавливаем нажатия на клавишу 'I AM RANDOM'  

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def game(message):
    if message.text == 'I AM RANDOM':
        # Подключаемся к БД
        db_worker = SQLighter(config.database_name)
        # Получаем случайную строку из БД
        # массив заранее генерируемых чисел берем с функции декоратора 
        row = db_worker.select_single(l[0]) # <<<<<<<

        markup = telebot.types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(True)
        markup.row('I AM RANDOM')

        # Отправляем данные
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, row[1] +'\n\n' + row[5], reply_markup=markup)
        db_worker.close()

...
```

p.s. цель получить строки в рандомном порядке из БД без повторения

Comment: 1 - добавьте свой код в вопрос, чтобы отвечающим не приходилось заново изобретать то, что вы описали словами. 2 - какую проблему вы пытаетесь решить? Почти уверен, что вы используете неподходящие инструменты.

Answer (score 3):

```
def dec1(fn):
    def wrap(*args, **kwargs):
        args = list(args)
        args[0] += 1
        kwargs.update(ar=args[0] + 100)

        n = fn.__name__
        res = dt[n] = dec2(num=222)(fn)(*args, **kwargs)
        return res
    return wrap


def dec2(num=1):
    def dec_(fn):
        def wrap(*args, **kwargs):
            args = list(args)
            args[0] = args[0] + kwargs.get('ar', 0) + num

            n = fn.__name__
            res = dt[n] = fn(*args)
            return res
        return wrap
    return dec_

@dec1
def asd1(a):
    return a


@dec2()
def asd2(a):
    return a

if __name__ == '__main__':
    dt = {}
    print(asd1(1))
    print(asd2(1))
    print(dt)
```

326

2

{'asd2': 2, 'asd1': 326}

Из декоратора dec1 вызываем декоратор dec2
Новые значения в dec2 можно передать через args/kwargs/num